# Dual boot w/ windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

I am completely not a computer expert but I would like to download Ubuntu. I have windows 10 currently and would like to keep it alongside with Ubuntu. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu setup will give you three options: "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10", This is the one you select if you are going to dual-boot. "Replace Windows 10 with Ubuntu", you can use this solution to erase Windows 10 and install Ubuntu. Or "Something Else", which allows you to resize partitions and you can select how much space the Ubuntu install will take up on your hard disk.